# Can we get this question about categories of merchants for rewards cards reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question is:
[How can I determine which stores are regarded as supermarkets for a rewards credit card?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/41885/10997)

This question was originally asking for a list of all merchants considered grocery stores in the US.  The accepted answer (mine) talks about how merchant category codes work and suggests a way to determine whether or not a store is categorized as a grocery store.

The question was closed as "seeking product or service recommendations."

The question has since been edited so that instead of asking for a list, it asks how to determine whether or not a store is considered a grocery store.  It's a good question that has [recently been asked again](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/48870/10997).  In my opinion, it should be reopened.

Anybody agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree it's now a good question and have reopened it.